# Option Menu from DISTINCT price to an option with Price range

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a option menu where the price is pulled out of the data base like:

```
$query_RS_Price = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT price FROM products WHERE Category LIKE %s AND Manufacturer = %s AND Color = %s");
```

This give me a range of values e.g 501, 999, 1000, , 1501 2000
I know i can make all the prices come up like so:

```
<?php  
              echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
             while ($Price = mysql_fetch_array($RS_Price)) {
    $selected3 = $_GET['price'] == $Price['price'] ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected3.'>' . $Price['price'] . '</option>';
} ?>
```

but this is not what I want.
I do not want to put all these in an option but I would like to make an option range like

```
<select name="price" class="dropmenu">

                 <option value="">Any</option>
                 <option value="0-500">£0-500</option>
                 <option value="500-1000">£500-1000</option>
                 <option value="1000-2000">£1000-2000</option>
                 <option value="2000">£2000&gt;</option>
               </select>
```

If there for example is no value between 0 and 500 I don't want to show the option.
 Is there away to show just the option ranges?
Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT case when price between 0 and 500 then '0-500'
            when price between 501 and 1000 then '501-1000'
            when price between 1001 and 2000 then '1001-2000'
            when price > 2000 then '>2000'
       end as price_range
FROM products 
WHERE Category LIKE %s AND Manufacturer = %s AND Color = %s
GROUP BY price_range
```

Comment: I have change it all however there is no output of a price range.I am outputting it like:  <select name="price" class="dropmenu">
                 <?php  
              echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
             while ($Price = mysql_fetch_array($RS_Price)) {
    $selected3 = $_GET['price'] == $Price['price'] ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected3.'>' . $Price['price'] . '</option>';
} ?>
                 </select> Is this the right way?

Comment: Sorted it just needed to change price to price_range. Thanks for all your help